# Docker ps doesn't show containers created/runing with docker-compose

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm trying to understand why I can't see containers created with ***docker-compose up -d*** using ***docker ps***. If I go to the folder where is the ***docker-compose.yaml*** located and run *docker-compose ps*  I can see the container runing. I did the same on windows because i'm using ubuntu and it works as expected, I can see the container just runing docker ps. Could anyone give me a hint about this behavior, please? Thanks in advance.

```
Environment:
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

in my terminal i see this output:

```
/GIT/project$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
/GIT/project$ cd scripts/
/GIT/project/scripts$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
/GIT/project/scripts$ docker-compose ps
    Name                  Command               State                       Ports                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scripts_db_1   docker-entrypoint.sh --def ...   Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp,:::3306->3306/tcp,    
                                                        33060/tcp                                    
/GIT/project/scripts$
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    # NOTE: use of "mysql_native_password" is not recommended: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password
    # (this is just an example, not intended to be a production configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - 3306
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - treip:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: changeit
      MYSQL_DATABASE: treip
volumes:
  treip:
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed the container with sudo and the problem was solve. now the container apear using `docker ps`, so instead of `docker-compose up` I executed it with sudo `sudo docker-compose up` . Sorry, my bad.